# Why are the functions called several times within the FlatMaps?

Tags: combine

I have the following code:

```
func myFunction() -> AnyPublisher<MyObject, MyError> {
   return self.globalPublisher
      // FlatMap 1
      .flatMap { value1 -> AnyPublisher<Object1, Error1 > in 
         return self.function1(value1)
      }
      // FlatMap 2
      .flatMap { value2 -> AnyPublisher<Object2, Error2 > in 
         return self.function1(value2)
      }
      // FlatMap3
      .flatMap { value3 -> AnyPublisher<Object3, Error3 > in 
         return self.function1(value3)
      }
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
   })
}
```

`myFunction` has only one subscriber (checked with debug). `globalPublisher` can be triggered multiple times and at any time. This triggers the whole `flatMap` logic.

When the `globalPublisher` is triggered for the first time, everything is fine: every function in every `flatMap` block is called once. But the second time happens something strange. The `globalPublisher` is triggered only once. The function in `FlatMap 1` is also triggered only once and returns only one value (checked with debug). But the function in `FlatMap 2` is suddenly triggered twice and returns two values. The function in `FlatMap 3` is then triggered 6 times.

The same thing happens for the third and further times: `globalPublisher` and the function in the `FlatMap 1` are triggered once and the `function1()` returns only one value. The rest is triggered several times and the number of triggers is getting bigger and bigger.

Could someone tell me what could be the reason for such strange behavior of FlatMaps? I have already gone through my code several times and debugged it. Actually, everything must work. I suppose it's possible that the global publisher is storing somehow the "subscriptions" of the FlatMaps? But I don't think it works that way. Do you have some ideas?

I suspect that the problem lies in the combination of a global publisher and all the FlatMaps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Di u try using `flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1))` ?

Comment: @BilalReffas Hi, Bilal. No. I have not tried this because I want to know the possible cause why this happens. With your suggestion, I simply fix the problem. But it does not disappear. I suspect that I use the FlatMaps incorrectly. I suspect that the problem lies in the combination of a global publisher and all the FlatMaps.

Comment: It's hard to help here since you show us neither the subscription site, nor the call site, nor what `globalPublisher` is, nor what `function1` is.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here.

**Either**

So `flatmap` has a `maxPublishers` parameter check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/flatmap(maxpublishers:_:)-3k7z5). The parameter is set default to 
 `.unlimited` which is controlling how many publishers the method can accept.

That's why your flatmaps are publishing these values unlimited. You need to change the parameter and set it to something like `flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1))`

**Or** 
You can use [switchToLatest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anypublisher/switchtolatest()-5j09p) which will always use the most recent provided publisher.

Comment: or possibly dennis_ka should be using [`switchToLatest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anypublisher/switchtolatest()-5j09p), not `flatMap`.

Comment: @robmayoff Your solution helped me. Thank you. Now all blocks and the functions in them are called exactly once. I don't know if I have solved the main problem, but it works correctly. 

@BilalReffas With `flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1))` this did not work. All blocks are only triggered once/for the first time (if I change `max` to `2`, then twice etc.). After that not anymore.